# Delete records from internal table and commit every 5000 record

Tags: abap

**Original statement** [delete all record from ldt_log_data and commit only once]

```
DATA:ldt_log_data TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF zwfm_t_logs.
DELETE zwfm_t_logs FROM TABLE ldt_log_data.

COMMIT WORK.
```

To optimize the performance of the delete statement, im trying to delete the record with the key COMM_GUID and commit every 5000 record.

[image: ZWFM_T_LOGS table]

My attempt:

```
LOOP AT ldt_log_data into w_ldt_log_data.
 
 delete table zwfm_t_logs from ldt_log_data with table key COMM_GUID = i_COMM_GUID.

COMMIT WORK.
```

I am getting stuck at how to delete the first 5000 and commit and continue this process until the deletion is completed. Any comment is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: and what is the value at the matter? what are the timings you are struggling with? I hardly imagine you can save a lot by deleting in batches, it will only slow down the deletion

Comment: Your recent update changed the topic of the question, which is why I rolled it back. You might want to post it as a new question. Or if you would like to discuss it with me, please copy it to a website like https://pastebin.com and post the link in a comment to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a `DELETE FROM TABLE`, then the whole table gets sent to the database, and the program execution continues when the database reports back. So you can't sneak a `COMMIT WORK` in there*.

An alternative would be to loop through the whole table doing single line DELETE's and do a COMMIT WORK whenever `sy-tabix MOD 5000 = 0`, but if your problem is performance, then that would be counter-productive because your program needs to wait for a database response for every single delete.

A compromise would be to copy the lines of your table into a new table in packets of 5000, send that table to the database and then do a database commit. You can copy a number of lines from one internal table to another by line index using the syntax `APPEND LINES OF itab_1 FROM idx1 TO idx2 TO itab_2`.

```
DATA: ldt_log_data TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF zwfm_t_logs,
      lt_tmp LIKE ldt_log_data,
      lv_from TYPE i.

CONSTANTS cv_package_size TYPE i VALUE 5000.

" code to fill ldt_log_data with the data you want to delete

lv_from = 1.

WHILE lv_from <= lines( ldt_log_data).
   APPEND LINES OF ldt_log_data 
          FROM lv_from TO lv_from + cv_package_size - 1
          TO lt_tmp.
   DELETE TABLE zwfm_t_logs FROM lt_tmp.
   COMMIT WORK.
   CLEAR lt_tmp.
   lv_from = lv_from + cv_package_size.
ENDWHILE.
```

<sub>* I could imagine that there might be databases which allow to do that through `%_HINTS`, but you didn't say which database you are using. And anyway, relying on db-specific hints should generally be avoided, because you don't know if you want to change your database backend some day.</sub>

Comment: @epiphany Why didn't you do it the way I wrote?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following pattern:

```
* Loop at your table
LOOP AT ...
  IF sy-tabix MOD 5000 = 0.
    COMMIT WORK.
  ENDIF.

* Delete the current record from DB
  DELETE ...
ENDLOOP:

COMMIT WORK.
```

A faster way to delete ALL records would be the following:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'DB_TRUNCATE_TABLE'
  EXPORTING
    tabname = 'ZWFM_T_LOGS'.

COMMIT WORK.
```